# How can I rewrite the following removing the date_format function?

Tags: mysql, performance, index

I have a table with a column `when` that is of type `datetime`.
I am doing the following filter which can not use and index:
`AND DATE_FORMAT(t1.when, '%Y-%m-%d') <= LAST_DAY(now() - interval 1 month )`
How can I re-write this so that I can get rid of the DATE_FORMAT that forbids index usage?

Comment: Have you tried the query without the function (`AND t1.when <= LAST_DAY(now() - interval 1 month`)?

Comment: @ChristianAmmer:I was not sure if it is the same

Answer (score 2):

The comment from  @ChristianAmmer is the key to answering your question. Why ???

First look the the WHERE clause

```
DATE_FORMAT(t1.when, '%Y-%m-%d') <= LAST_DAY(now() - interval 1 month )
```

You are forcing mysqld to evaluate `DATE_FORMAT(t1.when, '%Y-%m-%d')` for every row and comparing each result to `LAST_DAY(now() - interval 1 month )`. That quickly adds wear-and-tear on the query. I have discussed this before (See my answer to  [What happens when we take a timediff between timestamp and datetime](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56671/what-happens-when-we-take-a-timediff-between-timestamp-and-datetime/56676#56676)).

When comparing to `LAST_DAY(now() - interval 1 month )`, there is no need to do the [**DATE_FORMAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function against `t1.when`. Look at what actually happens when you do:

- You evaluate `DATE_FORMAT(t1.when, '%Y-%m-%d')` and the result is a string
- The string has to be converted back to a `DATE`
- That converted `DATE` is then compared to `LAST_DAY(now() - interval 1 month )`

These steps must be done  for every row.

To remove those steps, just switch the `WHERE` clause to have

```
AND t1.when <= LAST_DAY(now() - interval 1 month)
```

as @ChristianAmmer specified.

That way it compares `DATE` to `DATE` without any string manipulate or function call.

To answer your last comment

> @ChristianAmmer:I was not sure if it is the same

The comparison of the result is the same, but the way the comparison is executed is not.

Doing it with `AND t1.when <= LAST_DAY(now() - interval 1 month)` will always be faster. Leaving the `t1.when` on the left side of the comparison (left side of the equal sign) obligates the MySQL Query Optimizer to try using the index. Using a function call on the left side of the comparison eliminates index usage.

**CONCLUSION** : Go ahead an d use AND `t1.when <= LAST_DAY(now() - interval 1 month)`

## UPDATE 2014-04-15 10:46 EDT

To further prove function calls on the left side confuses the MySQL Query Optimizer, I have  other posts going back to 2011 that discuss how searching a FULLTEXT index cause the MySQL Query Optimizer to stop using other indexes (since you have to use the [**MATCH**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match) function on the left side).

- `May 07, 2012` : [MySQL EXPLAIN doesn't show 'use index' for FULLTEXT](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17502/mysql-explain-doesnt-show-use-index-for-fulltext/17545#17545)
- `Jan 26, 2012` : [Mysql fulltext search my.cnf optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11716/mysql-fulltext-search-my-cnf-optimization/11730#11730)
- `Oct 25, 2011` : [FULLTEXT index ignored in BOOLEAN MODE with 'number of words' conditional](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7136/fulltext-index-ignored-in-boolean-mode-with-number-of-words-conditional/7216#7216)
- `May 23, 2011` : [Optimizing mysql fulltext search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6092216/491757) (StackOverflow)